# Fantasy novel I read awhile ago about magic like tendrils in the air

Tags: story-identification, magic, young-adult, wizards

I read it a fairly long time ago, probably a good 15 to 20 years. I don't remember too many details but what I do remember is there was a kingdom in which the king had a magical sword that allowed him to control magic. He would see the magic like tendrils and at one point some magic from his sword came out and he grabbed the tendrils and put them back into the sword.

I remember he had an encounter with a wizard and after the wizard teleported away the tendrils of magic in the air were a mess and the king had to untangle them.

Unfortunately that is most of the details I remember. I've tried several times over the years to search for it on the internet but I've failed every time.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155822/what-is-the-name-of-these-books-this-series

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds like the [Enchanted Forest Chronicles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchanted_Forest_Chronicles) by Patricia C. Wrede

It is comprised of four books

1. Dealing with Dragons
2. Searching for Dragons
3. Calling on Dragons
4. Talking to Dragons

The current king of the enchanted forest can see the magic of the forest as tendrils in the air, and this network of magic tendrils keeps the forest alive.  He can sense when something is wrong in the forest through his sword which is tied into the network of magic.  Wizards in these books have staffs that steal ambient magic from around them and store it for later use.  The king at one point complains that this can cause the tendrils to knot up and then he has to undo it.  The stories have a lot of nods to different fairy tales in them and have a good lighthearted humor about them.

Here is a list of the main characters that appear throughout the books from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchanted_Forest_Chronicles)

> Humans
>
> Cimorene - A highly intelligent and strong-willed princess of Linderwall. The youngest of six beautiful sisters, she is unlike them in both personality and physical appearance, being tall and black-haired rather than blonde and petite.
>
> Zemenar - The Head Wizard of the Society of Wizards, given to being devious and under-handed. Grey-haired with a long, grey beard.
>
> Antorell - The son of Zemenar and a fairly incompetent wizard, with brown hair and beard. Antorell is consistently referred to as not being very smart or intimidating, and is easily manipulated by others.
>
> Morwen - A practical-minded and highly sensible witch who lives in the Enchanted Forest with her nine cats. She is short, with ginger hair and small square glasses. She infuriates Vamist in the third book with her nine cats (he thinks witches should only have one), none of whom are black, and the fact that she grows plain apples in her garden, among other things.
>
> Telemain - An academic magician whose goal in life is to discover the inner workings of every existing type of magic, and has a particular interest in learning the ways of the very secretive wizards. Moderate height with black hair and beard; has a tendency to indulge in overly long and complex technical explanations.
>
> Mendanbar - The King of the Enchanted Forest, an intelligent young man who does not particularly enjoy being king or "being 'Your Majestied' every third word". Tall and black-haired, marries Cimorene at the end of the second book.
>
> Alianora - The Princess of Duchy of Toure-on-Marsh, captured by Woraug, who becomes friends with Cimorene. Petite with crystallized honey hair. A major character in the first book.
>
> Vamist - Arona Michaelear Grinogion Vamist is a middle-aged, balding campaigner for traditional magic, causing many citizens of the world of the Enchanted Forest—including but not limited to fire-witches and witches that have more than one cat—to go into hiding, and forcing the rest to conform to his ideas of normalcy. A major character in the third book who meets a rather humorous end.
>
> Daystar - Cimorene and Mendabar's only child, fairly tall with black hair like his parents. Daystar is raised in secrecy by Cimorene, thus does not know his heritage, and is greatly confused when the Society of Wizards deems him a threat.
>
> Shiara - A fire-witch who aids Prince Daystar in his quest. She is not particularly polite, and frequently mouths off or bursts into tears at the slightest hint of stress due to her unstable fire-witch powers.
>
> Dragons
>
> Kazul - A high-ranking female dragon, with bright green scales, whom Cimorene runs away to work for. She becomes King of the dragons in the first book.
>
> Woraug - A distinctly unpleasant bright green dragon, who apparently dislikes Cimorene from the start.
>
> Tokoz - King of the Dragons before Kazul; appears only in the first book of the series.
>
> Roxim - An older dragon with a manner much like a favored uncle. His allergy to wizards (and their staffs) is particularly severe.
>
> Unnamed young dragon - Kazul's grandchild, arguably her "most irritating" one, and too young to pick a permanent name; travels with Prince Daystar.
>
> Animals
>
> Murgatroyd - one of Morwen's cats, male, quiet and reserved attitude.
>
> Fiddlesticks - one of Morwen's cats, seal brown male, large appetite (particularly for fish), fairly nosy when he's not involved in a conversation.
>
> Miss Eliza Tudor - one of Morwen's cats, white and fluffy female with blue eyes, as polite as can be expected.
>
> Scorn - one of Morwen's cats, calico female, lives up to her name, forms a relationship with Horatio.
>
> Jasmine - one of Morwen's cats, ginger female, lazy.
>
> Trouble - one of Morwen's cats, a large grey tom with a crooked tail and ragged ear, expresses some jealousy towards Horatio, generally lives up to his name.
>
> Jasper Darlington Higgins IV - one of Morwen's cats, cream and silver male.
>
> Chaos - one of Morwen's cats, grey long-haired tabby male, described as fat.
>
> Aunt Ophelia - one of Morwen's cats, spiky tortoiseshell female, speaks like a Southern Belle.
>
> Quiz - one of Morwen's cats, child of Scorn, also known as the Grand Inquisitor. Black and white, possibly a son of Horatio.
>
> Cassandra - one of Morwen's cats, child of Scorn, grey female, not very noticeable. (Possibly a daughter of Trouble, as Horatio and Scorn would have produced only black and white offspring.)
>
> Grendel - cat belonging to the witch Archaniz, fat black male, not very intelligent.
>
> Horatio - cat belonging to Brandel (a fire witch), black male with white paws and chin, forms a relationship with Scorn.
>
> Nightwitch - kitten belonging to Shiara, gifted by Morwen to her. She appears similar to Horatio and Quiz, is more than likely one of their descendants.
>
> Killer - rabbit that is affected by a number of spells throughout the book Calling on Dragons, by the end being a 7-foot 11-inch blue floating insubstantial winged donkey.

Comment: That is exactly the series I was looking to find! Can you give me some tips on how you found it? My Google searches weren't pointing in the right direction at all and I'd like to be better at researching answers.

Comment: @Quazimortal I've read it many times and own a copy of the four books bound as one volume :) The few details you were able to recall made me immediately think of this set.  As far as improving your search results the only advice I can offer it try different combinations of the details you have and see if anything even remotely rings a bell.  Or ask here :)