# Fantasy book where a princess encounters many fantasy tropes including a dragon

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, dragons

It was maybe in 2000-2012.

It was a fantasy book. I believe it combined a LOT of other fantasy works into one big story with a lot of popular characters from books and fairy tales and things.
I'm pretty sure every chapter started with "In which" so and so happened. 
Example- In which there was a dragon. In which the princess met a new friend. etc. I'm pretty sure the main character is a Princess. And there was likely a character, possibly a prince, named Touchstone.

Comment: [_Silverlock_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverlock) (and its "sequel" _The Moon's Fire-Eating Daughter_) by John Myers Myers combine characters from *everything*.

Comment: Chapters starting with "in which" + princess + dragon + mashing up fairy tales makes me think of the Enchanted Forest Chronicles (first one is Dealing With Dragons). No Touchstore, though there are several princess--one is named Therandil, and one gets turned into living stone and is called "the stone prince" throughout.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155822/what-is-the-name-of-these-books-this-series/155826 for additional details.

Comment: I think thats the one! Thanks.

Comment: why was this marked as a duplicate

Comment: Jon, just noticed your question.  For story id questions, mainly so they are all linked, any questions that have the same answer are marked as duplicates.

Comment: @Jon: Normally, it happens with an answer being provided and accepted, but we do also allow acceptance by comments (although at least one still needs an accepted answer, I think).

Answer (score 4):

King Touchstone is from *The Old Kingdom* series, by Garth Nix.

The publisher's blurb for the first book *Sabriel* (via Amazon):

> Since childhood, Sabriel has lived outside the walls of the Old Kingdom, away from the power of Free Magic, and away from the Dead who refuse to stay dead. But now her father, the Abhorson, is missing, and Sabriel must cross into that world to find him. With Mogget, whose feline form hides a powerful, perhaps malevolent spirit, and Touchstone, a young Charter Mage, Sabriel travels deep into the Old Kingdom. There she confronts an evil that threatens much more than her life and comes face-to-face with her own hidden destiny. . . .

Comment: Ya I've heard of a few touchstones before, its not that series.

Answer (score 2):

The combining of other popular fairy tales in one, with a princess as main character, can be found in Jim C. Hines' *Princess* series (e.g. *Red Hood's Revenge* - her friend is Snow White, and so on). There's the Mermaid, Sleeping Beauty and the rest of the gang. There be dragons as well.

Don't remember a Touchstone there, though, and the chapters aren't prefixed with the quaint 'In which...' description.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that there is a Touchstone, i could be remembering it from another series. But i do know i have read 2 book series with Touchstones, one being sabriel, which is not what i'm thinking of.